# how can i draw indian rupee symbol in raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

**Is any know how to draw an indian rupees symbol using raphael.**

please provide me a useful solution.

Comment: Can Raphaël draw text? ₨

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/fonts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Adobe Illustrator draw any symbol/path you want, export as SVG, open in text editor, copy/paste the path into your Raphael code, use it

Comment: If you don't have access to Adobe Illustrator, you can do the same thing using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).  It's free.  Also, if you don't know how to draw the vector shape, you can download it [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Indian_Rupee_symbol.svg).

Answer (score 5):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4cJdM/)

```
var rupee = paper.path("M152.511,23.119h41.031L209.256-0.5H55.214L39.5,23.119h26.739c27.086,0,52.084,2.092,62.081,24.743H55.214 L39.5,71.482h91.769c-0.002,0.053-0.002,0.102-0.002,0.155c0,16.974-14.106,43.01-60.685,43.01l-22.537-0.026l0.025,22.068 L138.329,249.5h40.195l-93.42-116.709c38.456-2.074,74.523-23.563,79.722-61.309h28.716l15.714-23.62h-44.84 C162.606,38.761,158.674,29.958,152.511,23.119z").attr({fill:'black',stroke:'none'});
```